# Active Batch - Using variable inside a SQL active variable

Tags: sql, powershell, automation, activebatch

I am trying to set up automation for a process in which I want to use SQL variables. There is no problem with this part of it as long as I use this script, I can run the jobs in **one** environment.

```
SELECT DatabaseServer FROM v_view WHERE Profile = 'Profile1' AND Environment = 'TEST'
```

However, I would like to solve it by putting a variable in the variable I grab from SQL, and depending on which "folder" in Active Batch it is in, it will utilize that variable.

```
SELECT DatabaseServer FROM v_view WHERE Profile = '$Variable' AND Environment = 'TEST'
```

Is there any way to do this? Maybe using a Powershell script and inserting the SQL query into it?

Comment: Sure, but it depends how you execute the query from ActiveBatch. The best way would be to use parametrized queries.

Comment: It looks like this:

Profile1:
 - Powershell copy (uses fs server parameter)
 - SQL query (uses instance, and db parameter)
Profile2:
 - Powershell copy (uses fs server parameter)
 - SQL query (uses instance, and db parameter)

And so on…
So what should the parameter look like?
SELECTDatabaseServer FROM v_view WHERE Profile =$'if you use this parameter on Profile1 return=Profile1' AND Environment = 'TEST'